# como llenar el campo de un formulario desde una consulta Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    <?php

    include("conexion.php");
    $idUsu=$_POST["id"];

    $sql="SELECT Nombre FROM usuario where idUsuario=$idUsu"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    ?>
```

y aqui el formulario donde quiero mostrar el nombre

```
    <form >
    <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputNombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="Nombre" value="$result">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que debes hacer es crear un arreglo asociativo por medio de un `while` y luego abrir el lenguaje php con sus respectivas etiquetas `<?php ?>` dentro del formulario de la siguiente manera:

```
 <?php 
    include("conexion.php");
        $idUsu=$_POST["id"];
        $sql="SELECT Nombre FROM usuario where idUsuario=$idUsu"; 
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        }
    ?>
   <label for="inputNombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="Nombre" value="<?php echo 
    $res['nombre']; ?>">
```